# use desc for data sort in cakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I write function for view data with order desc but that not work!

my function is:

```
 $this->loadModel('User');
    $users = $this->User->find('first', array(
        'order' => array('User.id' => 'desc')
    ));
```

I can't use order desc in cakephp 2.6.7 controller, how can i correct my function ?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Have you checked the query being generated by Cake for this find?

Comment: This query will result in just one and the last record record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to retrieve all data in descending order by id. But you set 'first'. it should be 'all'.

**try this:**

```
 $this->loadModel('User');
        $users = $this->User->find('all', array(
            'order' => array('User.id' => 'desc')
        ));
```

Comment: You should still be able to sort the records using `find('first')` as you may want to retrieve just the first matching record for specific conditions.